# Why is the last row of the collectionView not aligned properly?

Tags: ios, swift, collectionview, flowlayout

I am working on the collectionView layout as below:

[image]

But the last row is not getting align properly not sure why?

Here is the collectionView setup code:

```
func numberOfSections(in collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int {
    return 1
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return 7
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    if let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "\(collectionViewCell.self)", for: indexPath) as? collectionViewCell {
        cell.imageView.backgroundColor = .black
        return cell
    }
    return UICollectionViewCell()
}
```

Here is the implementation of the flow layout delegate method:

```
let sectionInsets = UIEdgeInsets(top: 30.0, left: 20.0, bottom: 30.0, right: 20.0)

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView,
                    layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout,
                    sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {

    if indexPath.row == 2 { // This item should occupy the entire available width
        let paddingSpace = sectionInsets.left + sectionInsets.right
        let availableWidth = collectionView.frame.width - paddingSpace
        let widthPerItem = availableWidth
        return CGSize(width: widthPerItem, height: (widthPerItem / 2))
    }
    
    // adjust 2 cells in the single row
    let paddingSpace = sectionInsets.left * (itemsPerRow + 1)
    let availableWidth = collectionView.frame.width - paddingSpace
    let widthPerItem = availableWidth / itemsPerRow
    
    return CGSize(width: widthPerItem, height: widthPerItem)
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView,
                    layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout,
                    insetForSectionAt section: Int) -> UIEdgeInsets {
    return sectionInsets
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView,
                    layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout,
                    minimumLineSpacingForSectionAt section: Int) -> CGFloat {
    return sectionInsets.left
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What you are seeing is normal for a flow layout. All rows are left and right justified *except* for the last row, which is left justified only. It’s just like a printed book: the last line of a paragraph does not get spaced out to touch the right margin.

Comment: Thanks, matt for your answer. I was not aware that it is the default behavior. Is there is the way I can align the last row similar to the other so that it looks symmetrical?

Comment: By the way, if I remove the element from the second row which occupies full width of the screen. Then the last row looks similar to the other. Is this issue because of that row?

Comment: You'd need to subclass the flow layout class to change the way it lays out. Alternatively, look into compositional layouts, which are much better for almost everything.

Comment: OK another thing I recommend is that instead of trying to play around so dynamically, if you know when the long cell is coming, use three sections instead of one. Now each can have its own layout rules. I can trivially create your layout of 7 cells by using a compositional layout in three sections. Basically it's a matter of the right tool for the job.

Comment: Thanks matt for your response I already created this with compositional layout but the only problem with that is I cannot support below iOS 13.

Comment: I was afraid you might say that. :)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. But I could fix by setting `collectionView(_:layout:minimumInteritemSpacingForSectionAt:)`.